# recursive insert only inserts first element python bst

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement insert function of bst but my recursive approach only inserts the first value. My approach was to traverse until the empty child and set that node to new value.

```
class BSTNode(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def insert(self, val):
    if self.root is None:
        self.root = BSTNode(val)
    else:
        self.insertNode(self.root,val)

def insertNode(self,node, val):
    if node is None:
        node = BSTNode(val)
        return 
    elif val <= node.val:
        node.left = self.insertNode(node.left, val)
    elif val > node.val:
        node.right = self.insertNode(node.right, val)

bst = new BST()
bst.insert(5)
bst.insert(10)
```

Comment: There appears to be a missing BST class and/or `import` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning `BSTNode` in `insertNode` (so you create a node but return `None`). You should do this instead:

```
if node is None:
    return BSTNode(val)
```

So the full method becomes:

```
def insertNode(self, node, val):
    if node is None:
        return BSTNode(val)
    elif val <= node.val:
        node.left = self.insertNode(node.left, val)
    elif val > node.val:
        node.right = self.insertNode(node.right, val)
    return node
```

Comment: im pretty sure this code is still broken ... because in most cases insertNode will return None

Comment: @JoranBeasley with some assumptions, it works: https://trinket.io/python/530b34694e

Comment: why is the `return node` needed? I thought the return was only needed to break the recursion.

Comment: @hmaxx If we don't return `node`, `node.left` (or `node.right`) in the previous call in the recursion stack will be assigned to `None`, which we don't want.

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful to first create a node class... it's easier to think of a node alone than it is to think about a Tree.

```
class Node:
   def __init__(self,value):
       self.value = value
       self.left = None
       self.right = None
   def insert_value(self,value):
       # there are 3 cases
       if not self.value: # in one case this node has no value
           self.value = value
       elif value < self.value: # if value is less than this nodes value
           # then insert it to the left
           if not self.left:
               self.left = Node(value)
           else:
               self.left.insert_value(value)
       else: # otherwise if value is greater than or equal to this nodes value
           # then insert it to the right
           if not self.right:
               self.right = Node(value)
           else:
               self.right.insert_value(value)
```

Once you have this `Node` class the tree implementation becomes trivial.

```
class BST:
    def __init__(self,root_value=None):
        self.root = Node(root_value)
    def insert_value(self,value):
        self.root.insert_value(value)

bst = BST()
bst.insert_value(5)
bst.insert_value(10)
print(bst.root)
```

Now you certainly do not have to solve this in this fashion ... but it makes it easier to reason about (at least for me).

Comment: Though the code provided works, I'd argue that implementing [`Binary Search Tree`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) logic for a [`Node`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node) class is of poor style. The inserting logic should be handled by the tree, not the node, similar to how the sorting logic when sorting a list is handled by the sorting method, not by the elements of the list.

Comment: yeah you are right ... but that said it makes it a tiny bit easier to reason with imho ... but you are correct that in general this would probably fall into bad practice